# Windows environment variables and manual registry editing - no/wrong values issue

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Open `regedit.exe`, navigate to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`. Create two environment variables:

```
Name   Type            Data
-----  --------------  -----------
zbar   REG_SZ          water
zfoo   REG_EXPAND_SZ   %zbar%
```

Open new `cmd.exe`, `powershell.exe` or whatever. These variables are **missing**. Make LogOff, then LogOn. In `cmd.exe` window type `echo %zbar%` - `water` is displayed. Type `echo %zfoo%` and `%zbar%` is displayed, but I expect to see expanded value - `water`.

And now. Open Windows *Environment Variables* dialog. Alter or create any variable (for example `zzz=zzz`). Reopen `cmd.exe` and type `echo %zfoo%` - now you see `water`!

Actually, I am creating these variables with PowerShell script. But all this script does is described registry manipulations.

**Questions:**

1. How to force `zfoo` variable to have a correct value without that magic with opening Windows *Environment Variables* dialog and altering some variables? Maybe I should call some API, something like `[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::Refresh()`?
2. It is possible to make these variables visible to users without need for LogOff/LogOn operations? If I edit user-level environment variables (also in registry) they are immediately available, but with global - they are not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to [broadcast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms644932(VS.85).aspx) the [WM_SETTINGCHANGE Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms725497(VS.85).aspx).

Remember: You're not actually setting any environment variables of any form when you modify the registry.  Environment variables are part of each individual process' memory space, with each process having its own set.  They don't live in the registry.  You are changing a *template*.  You need to persuade the programs that set *actual* environment variables to re-read the template and set their environments accordingly.  You do that by broadcasting a Windows message that tells any interested parties that the template in the registry has changed.  Microsoft Windows Explorer is one such interested party, and modifies its own environment variables whenever it hears that the template has changed.  These modifications are then inherited in the normal way by any new process that Explorer spawns.

Comment: Yes, you need to broadcast `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` (though only windows that specifically handle it will actually pick up the changes), but also, note that even then, when you make a(ny) change, *any* variables that contain other variables will stop getting expanded until you reboot (including ones that already existed). It’s a weird bug (in *at least* XP and 7) that I’ve banged my head against countless times.

Comment: For a source code example in C#, see also **[here @ StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705691/1016343)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SETX, it will broadcast WM_SETTINGCHANGE after setting variable:

```
SETX VAR VALUE /M
```

Or, if you insist to enter the variables into the registry, you can have SETX
set a variable that already exists, in order to broadcast the registry change:

```
SETX OS %OS% /M
```